# open an image from a scrollview into a new viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollView which contains multiple UIImageViews.

I want to know which UIImageView was tapped from the scrollview.

Thanks

Comment: There can be several possible ways for this - 1. You can add a view on that with full bounds. 2. You can push one modal/navigation-view controller on current controller on click of image.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? 1) Knowing which UIImageView was tapped. 2) getting the UIImage from that UIImageView. 3) switching to another view controller. 4) tell the new view controller which UIImage to display?

Comment: you want to make it like gallery view?

Comment: @sch: I need help with 1) Knowing which UIImageView was tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add gesture recognizer to image view and then open it in view controller (modal)

Use **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** delegate

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
gestureTap.delegate = self;
gestureTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[image addGestureRecognizer:gestureTap];
[gestureTap release];



- (void)doubleTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"double tap on %@", gesture.view);

}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I need to know which UIImage was tapped. Any suggestions?

Comment: In doubleTap, gesture.view is the UIImageView that was tapped. you can get the UIImage from that: UIImage *tappedImage = [(UIImageView *) gesture.view image];